# vpn connection and ip problem

Tags: ip-address, vpn

i have one application who use to connect to server via VPN.

i can put server name or Ip in application to connect to server.

If i put IP & Connect to VPN (this work fine except if any other computer on network have same ip(of remote server)application stop).

and if i put server name after connecting to VPN, server name is not resolved to IP.

i am using windows7 Ultimate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open up a command prompt(start menu, cmd) and try to ping the server by name you'll probably find you aren't resolving the address properly when VPN'd.

That is a name resolution problem, not a VPN problem.

The name resolution issue is something your VPN administrator should fix, but you can force your computer to resolve correctly by adding an entry in your HOSTS file located at %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\HOSTS .  You can edit it with notepad.

```
#Entry would look like
1.2.3.4 servername
```

Comment: yes true, i am facing same issue... can you tell me how to resolve it...?